# manipulating css on jquery ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an html file with a hidden button. After i do a jquery `$.ajax` call, i want to show the button in the content. So i tried

```
//...
dataType: html,
success: function(data) {
    $('.somediv').append(data);
    $('input').show(); //the button in the data content that i want to display
}
//...
```

Is there any other way to solve this?

If i use a  tag in the top of the loaded content, i can solve it that way. But it feels like a bad solution.

Edit: html + js from "data": http://jsfiddle.net/JvyBw/

Comment: But what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: That the ` $('input')` remains hidden

Comment: Why don't you include it **visible** in the data content, so it will appear together will all the data, right?  I thought you did that.

Comment: @Shomz I load this content on several places and i only want to show the buttons in some cases.

Comment: No idea what's wrong there, probably something you didn't show here... Are you using visibility: hidden instead of display: none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
$('.somediv')
    .append(data)
    .find('input')
         .show();
```

Comment: @Johan Could you post the HTML that is returned and being stored in `data`? (edit it into your question)

Comment: Ok, please see the edit. Forgot to att display: none on the generated buttons here, but you get the idea. :)

Comment: Where is the css for the class sid?

Comment: @EdHeal Theres no css, just a class to bind the keyup event